# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusListenerConfigHelper

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, slf4j

What could be the reason behind this error ?
When we will get this error ? slf4j jar is already in package

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/util/StatusListenerConfigHelper
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:147)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.InstrumentMain$LoggerWrapper.<init>(InstrumentMain.java:165)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.InstrumentMain$LoggerWrapper.<init>(InstrumentMain.java:164)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.InstrumentMain.<clinit>(InstrumentMain.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusListenerConfigHelper
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem in your classpath between two versions of logback. If you use a tool like maven to manage dependencies, you have to find which dependency import the oldest logback version and exclude logback from it.